# preview with lualatex dvipng replacement?

Tags: luatex, texstudio

Maybe this is TexStudio related not the general question.
preview with pdflatex comlier works fine.
when i switched to lulalatex preview command fail.
i use

> lualatex --output-format=dvi -interaction=nonstopmode "\input"
>   "test.tex"

font used is: Arial Unicode MS.

compilation error:

> ! LuaTeX error (DVI back-end): no output function for "pdf_literal"
>   whatsit.
>        
>                      \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
>       l.31 \end{document}

and dvi file is empty (no fonts loaded/embeded)
is there like pdf2png which can be used with lualatex?

Comment: The preview screen of TeXStudio uses `dvipng`, which is based on the DVI format that doesn't support OpenType fonts. There's currently no replacement.

Comment: Your document (or a package it loads) is using pdf/luatex commands to insert literal pdf into the output, that only works when generating pdf. Imagemagic convert can be used to convert pdf to png

Comment: Without an example of your input, we can't really tell what exactly the source of the issue is. However, as commented, it's at least possible that you are loading package(s) that need PDF-mode specials. Please edit in an example and we can reopen.